# Commit message with --no-verify with git kraken

Tags: gitkraken

I want to ignore git hook in some scenario i have.

How can i commit using `gitKraken` while specifying `--no-verify` flag.

Thanks.

Comment: @BSeitkazin How this related to the question?

Comment: or push with `--no-verify` for that matter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible as of GitKraken 9.1. https://help.gitkraken.com/gitkraken-client/current/#bypass-git-hooks.

There is a little arrow at the far-right of commit button that opens a popup where you can select "Commit and skip hooks"

[image: commit and skip hooks]

Comment: This answer needs more recognition!

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**
This is now possible as of GitKracken 9.1. See the answer by @jaredbeach above

---

Unfortunately, it is not currently possible: https://twitter.com/GitKraken/status/1067485533738196992

Comment: Vote for this feature here: https://feedback.gitkraken.com/suggestions/199376/add-ability-to-bypass-git-hooks

Comment: This answer is no longer true, check the other answer in this Question.